# How to get 5 hours back trend in Twitter?

Tags: api, twitter

I know how to get the current trends of Twitter for a specific location, but is there any way to get 5 hours back trend in Twitter using API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter REST API does not support this sort of inquiry.  To accomplish this, you would need to have your application poll the trends every hour (or so) and store them in a database.  You could then query that database however you like.